# Plugins necessary to integrate Specflow with Jira

Tags: automated-tests, jira, bdd, specflow, jira-zephyr

I want to integrate manual testing and automated testing in Jira.

I use Specflow in .Net with `NUnit` and Jenkins.

In Jira it's installed the Zephyr plugin:

> Zephyr for Jira - Test Management for JIRA (Server) 2000 Users: Commercial License

From my research to integrate everything I will need also:

1. Cucumber for Jira (is this necessary?)
2. BDD feature for Zephyr should be enabled
3. Zephyr Squad plugin

Do I need something also for Jenkins?

Did I understand correctly? Is it another way to integrate them?

Comment: Just a quick glance at Zephyr, and I'm not sure if there is integration with SpecFlow. They mention [cucumber](https://cucumber.io/) quite a bit. That is a different Gherkin implementation than SpecFlow.

Comment: Since SpecFlow uses an underlying unit test provider, you might have better luck integrating NUnit with Jira: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Integration-C-Nunit-Selenium-results-with-Jira/qaq-p/1214075

Comment: In your case SpecFlow is just a fancy way of writing NUnit tests.

Comment: Looks like there is no direct integration between SpecFlow and Jira: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Any-plans-for-SpecFlow-and-JIRA-integration/qaq-p/379097